# Error installing package using Getit Manager

Tags: delphi, ide

I'm trying to install "Essentials for VCL" into Delphi 10.4.2 running on Win 10 Pro 64b
using the Getit Manager. I get the following error:

[image: Getit Dialog]

Can I manually install the package?

Comment: There is an extraction path. Go there and open the packages for installing them

Comment: This is a clearly a bug, you need to report it to Embarcadero Support.